# changing frame of UIScrollview not working in iOS xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.

I dragged out UIScrollView in IB, connected it to UIViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

in UIViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 300, 500);
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 600);
    _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    NSLog(@"x-pos:%f y-pos:%f width:%f height:%f of uiscrollview", _scrollview.frame.origin.x, _scrollview.frame.origin.y, _scrollview.frame.size.width, _scrollview.frame.size.height);
}
```

I get NSLog :

```
x-pos:0.000000 y-pos:200.000000 width:300.000000 height:500.000000 of uiscrollview
```

But I see nothing...

I googled some, and found out maybe it's because of the Auto-Layout enabled?

I'm guessing the auto-layout set my UIScrollView's height and width to 0.

But I need to use Autolayout for other elements.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: In which method are you doing all this?? "ViewDidLoad" ?? or some other method?

Comment: in viewdidload. I edited my question to include viewdidload

Comment: The initial Layout of views from sotryboard/Xib files is completed in "viewDidLayoutSubviews". Try doing these changes in this method.

Comment: Yes, actually I just tried doing it in ViewWillApear, and saw that all contents inside the UIScrollView are stacked together at the topleft of the screen. But NSLog still shows uiscrollview has width and height.. still it's white, not gray as it's supposed to be.

Comment: With Autolayout, have you provided constraints for scrollView in stroyboard?

Comment: putting them inside viewDidLayoutSubviews  worked! thank you. I wish I could mark your comment as the answer

Comment: you may do that now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 300, 500);
    _scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 600);
    _scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    NSLog(@"x-pos:%f y-pos:%f width:%f height:%f of uiscrollview", _scrollview.frame.origin.x, _scrollview.frame.origin.y, _scrollview.frame.size.width, _scrollview.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The contentSize is to the scroll region of the scroll view, the frame (or the bounds) is the size of the frame you set. You can imagine that the frame is the window you see on your interface but the contentSize and the contentOffset mean your whole region in the scroll view.